# Is it possible to decrease height distance between DropdownMenuItem's in DropdownButton without rewriting Flutter sources?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to make the height distance between DropdownMenuItem's 10 times less than by default but can't. Is it possible without rewriting Flutter sources? If not, anyway it is unclear where in dropdown.dart (a file in Flutter sources) the height is set. Code like:

```
DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                 value: value,
                 child: Container(height: smallerHeight, Text(value))
               );
```

does not help!)

[image: Image with the problem.]

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to increase the size the of the box then you can use `SizedBox` to force constraints(by setting height or width) of the DropDOwnMenuItem. By default the `DropDownMenuItem` takes _kMenuItemHeight as its height, so you can enforce a larger height by using `SizedBox` inside the `DropDOwnMenuItem`.

Comment: I don't know the way to decrease height without making changes to the DropDownMenuItem class.